# jquery plugin to convert a <select size="10"> to a usable list on Safari mobile (iOS)

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, mobile-safari

Safari for iOS ignores the size attribute of `<select>` elements. It always renders a one-line high drop down instead of a multi-line list box.

In our case, I use a multi-line  to display a list and we don't want the user experience that iOS produces in this case.

Can you recommend a jquery plugin that converts a `<select size="10">` to something that looks like a list and that will be usable on Safari mobile?

Comment: can you provide screen-shots of what you are getting? i'm not understanding what you mean

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/9Dpga/10/ on your computer vs on your Safari mobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the OP, I wrote a plugin to solve my problem. See https://github.com/redhotsly/safarimobile-multiline-select.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Select box factory](http://www.headcircus.com/uiguy/selectboxfactory/selectboxfactory.html) which uses jQuery to make it's own lists.